# Complete the numerical sequence

Tags: number-sequence

Complete the following sequence:
\begin{align}
0 \quad&\quad 1&2&\quad\quad3&4&\quad\quad5&6&\quad\quad7&8\\
\hline\\
1\quad&\quad3&7&\quad\quad12&23&\quad\quad40&74&\quad\quad139&?\\
\end{align}
**Hints**

- It is a positive integer number.

Comment: Oh, come on! Still 1 answer ? I really don't wanna answer my own question. The pattern isn't hard to find if you look the numbers closely. Well maybe just a bit :)

Answer (score 2):

My guess:

> 270

Reasoning:

> Look at the differences between the numbers:
>
>  2,4, 5,11, 17,34, 65,...
>
>  They seem to come in pairs, where the second one is twice the first one, or twice the first one plus one.
>  Continuing this pattern, the new difference must be 131, and the solution is 270.

Comment: 17 does not fit that pattern